# Django, counting results of complex queries gives incorrect results

Tags: django

Running a query that filters by counting annotations returns the correct results, however when I try to count the results of the query grouped by street name, the counts are incorrect. I have tried removing the `order_by`, but that shouldn't matter because 'street_name' is also in the `values_list` I am creating.

```
class Voter(models.Model):
   ...
   street_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   precinct    = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   ...

class VoterHistory(models.Model):
   reg_number = models.ForeignKey(Voter)
   election_type = models.CharField(max_length=8)

# The voter query works correctly on its own.
voters = Voter.objects.filter(
         # VoterHistory filters
         # Voters that have voted more than once with an election_type of PRI
            voterhistory__election_type__startswith = "PRI"
         ).annotate(
            election_count=Count('voterhistory__election_type')
         ).filter(
            election_count__gte=1

         # extra filters
         ).filter(
            precinct=10
         )

# Counting does not work if the voter history filters are included in the voter query
counts = voters.values_list('street_name').annotate(Count('street_name')).order_by('street_name')
```

Comment: Can you share more information about what you expect it to return and what it's actually returning?